# AttributeError: module 'regex' has no attribute 'compile'

Tags: python, nltk

Code:

```
import re
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import  PorterStemmer
```

the error I am getting while I am running the below code

```
AttributeError: module 'regex' has no attribute 'compile'
```

I use `spyder` and the package `nlkt` is up to date. The code runs when I open `spyder` once then it stops working.

Comment: Please show your code. You only showed us the imports. You said you're using `spyder` but where's the `spyder` code?

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason would be that you are shadowing the `re` module. Have you named any script `re.py`? If so, choose a different name.

Comment: the error message doesn't mention the `re` module. It mentions a different module called `regex`, which is not in the standard library. Apart from that, I agree that it is likely caused by module shadowing (filename `regex.py`). I guess the [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) library is used by nlkt. It has some nice unicode features lacking in the standard library re module.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working for me:

```
import regex as re
re._pattern_type = re.compile('')
```

Where then I am using it something like:

```
# Iterate through the documentation content
for title, content in _docs.items():
    # Clean the content and update documents, classes, and words
    pattern = re.compile('[\W_]+')
    cleaned_content = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern.sub(' ', content))
    cleaned_content = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w.lower()) for w in cleaned_content if w not in ignore_words]
    documents.append((cleaned_content, title))
    classes.add(title)
    words.update(cleaned_content)
```